# Only the border color of selected image must change. And when I click on some image inside div previous image selection must removed

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular8

[image] Any Help would be very much appreciated! I'm working on Angular8. For further assistance, I also watched an image in which you can see all the div are being selected on whichever image I click. Instead of removing border effect from the previous image and showing only on selected div.

**My HTML Code**

```
                  <img
                  src="{{category?.CategoryImage || 'https://giftclubimagestorage.blob.core.windows.net/images/biryani.jpg'}}"
                  class="rounded-circle"
                  alt="{{category?.CategoryTitle || ''}}" class="imgrr">

            </div>
          </div>
```

**My CSS Code**

```
.icon:hover {

border: 2px solid red;

}
.selitem
{
  border: 20px solid blue;

}
```

**My TS Code**

```
  [![public sel(event): void {
    const divs = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      if (divs\[i\] !== event.target) {
        divs\[i\].className = 'icon';
      }
    }
    event.target.className = 'selitem';
  }]
```

Answer (score 0):

For this I would have every image that is a select-able have a class such as `.selectable` and on click point to a function such as:

```
function clickHandler(element) { 
  // Get currently selected element(s)
  const old = document.getElementsByClassName("selectable"); 
  
  for (i = 0; i < old.length; i++) {
    // Remove current selected class
    console.log(old[i].classList.remove("selected"));
    } 
  // On element that called the function add selected class
  element.classList.add("selected");
}
```

Live example on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/36pszgxo/15/

Comment: I tried it, but gives me the error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined at Component.click Handler"

Comment: In my example I am calling the function from the html like 
`<div onclick="clickHandler(this)">` using `this` to pass a reference to the element it is called from. If you call the handler from elsewhere you will need to make sure you pass the element as an argument